# React bootstrap overlaytrigger throwing a warning about unique key in iterator

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue with the React bootstrap OverlayTrigger component.I am getting a warning `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` I would normally add key prop as the warning says but OverlayTrigger is missing this prop according to doc. How can I resolve it?

```
const mappedTags = tags.map(tag => {
            if(tag.battery === 1) {
                return (
                    <MenuItem key={tag.id} eventKey={tag.name}>{tag.name}</MenuItem>
                )
            }
            else {
                return (
                    <OverlayTrigger placement="right" overlay={tooltip}>
                        <MenuItem key={tag.id} eventKey={tag.name} disabled>{tag.name}</MenuItem>
                    </OverlayTrigger>
                )
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You map the `tags` to a function that returns `<MenuItem` or `<OverlayTrigger`, and each of them should have a `key` prop.

You can solve this by adding the `key={tag.id`} also to the `<OverlayTrigger`:

```
<OverlayTrigger key={tag.id} placement="right" overlay={tooltip}>
    <MenuItem key={tag.id} eventKey={tag.name} disabled>{tag.name}</MenuItem>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Regarding your comment about "OverlayTrigger is missing this prop according" - the `key` is a property that you can use in any jsx object, it's not something specific to the `OverlayTrigger` object.

Comment: thank you by specifying the JSX object. I'll accept as soon as it allows me.

Comment: happy to help :)